# Detecting a click inside a UIWebView - not on a link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, click

I want to enable some functionality that is triggered by clicking on the screen. the view of the screen is a UIWebView, and I'd like to be able to tell when the user clicks on it, though not when he clicks on a link inside of it, but any other place.

Any Ideas?
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `touchesBegan:` / `touchesEnded:` in the [**`UIResponder Class Reference`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how we'll the two will combine together, as one might "Snatch" the others touch events... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

look at this code snippet. it might help you.

```
NSSet                   *touch;
CGPoint                 mTouchLocation;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
touch = [event allTouches];
mTouchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSLog(@"touchesMoving");
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"touchEnded");
CGPoint newTouchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];  
}
```

touchesBegan is invoked when user touched the screen, touchesMoved when the user move the finger holding the screen and touchesEnded is when the touch is released.